# Font size change using buttons in android studio

Tags: android

I have a layout contain text like bellow [with share button and increase and decrease button at up side]

[image: preview image]

Now, i want to make a code that make increase and decrease button make the font size of the text changes

whats the way plz

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="مشاركة الذكر"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_icon">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/increase_text"
    android:title="تكبير الخط"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/increas_icon">
</item>
<item  android:id="@+id/decrease_text"
    android:title="تصغير الخط"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/decrease_icon">
</item>
<item  android:id="@+id/coppy_text"
    android:title="نسخ النص"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/coppy_icon">
</item>
```

and this is the main code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id==R.id.share)
        Toast.makeText(this,"share",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the followinng code

```
//init your textview and an int to record the textsize and change in textsize int
private TextView myTextView;
private int textSize = 20; //lets say default font size is 20sp
private int diff = 5;

//define your textview

//now the main part

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.increase_text){
        textSize = textSize+diff;
        myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
    }else if(id == R.id.decrease_text){
        textSize = textSize-diff;
        myTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: what if i want to make multi changes not only one size as u said... i mean 14,18,20,25 etc >> not only on change.. can u help me ?

Comment: please elaborate i didn't get u

Comment: i mean if i press increase button text size increase to be 15 from 10 if i pressed again ints increase to 20 from 15 press again increase from 20 to 25 and etc ..... same thing when i press decrease button .. can u help me plz

Comment: thats what i have told you brother